# ggplot: adding new data to the existing grouped boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I created a grouped boxplot with ggplot2. Now I want to add additional data to the existing plot in the following way:
for each month I have **one** "Optimal" value that should be displayed as a dot and these dots should be connected by a line. This is the desired state:

[image: Ggplot with dots]

How could I add those dots and lines to my plot?
Can I by any chance put the connecting lines behind the boxplots?

Here is my current state and the data:

1. Ggplot without dots :
   [image: Grouped boplot]
2. Data frame:[Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGdM9.png)

R Code:

```
data("MyData")
MyData$Month <- as.factor(MyData$Month)

head(MyData)

MyPlot <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Month, y=Note, fill=Treatment)) + 
  geom_boxplot()   
MyPlot
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an geom mapping the y to a different variable. For the sake of simplicity, I moved some of the aesthetics to the geom_boxplot.

```
MyPlot <- ggplot(MyData, aes(x=Month)) + geom_boxplot(aes(y=Note, fill=Treatment)
MuPlot <- MyPlot + geom_pointline(aes(y=Optimum), colour="green", stroke="black")
```

This will however not add you points to the legend, as ggplot2 does not support multiple encodings of the same scale (i.e. using both Treatment and a separate variable for colour).

The geom `geom_pointline` is from the 'lemon' package.

On a second note, try this for the second line:

```
MuPlot <- MyPlot + geom_pointline(aes(y=Optimum, colour="Optimum"), stroke="black") + scale_colour_manual(values('Optimum'='green'))
```

Comment: Dear @MrGumble,
thank you very much for the hint! I created a separate file for the "optimal" values and it worked out!

Comment: You're welcome! But for future reference, please make a minimal working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you are almost there with code and expected output! It's really difficult to extract the data from an image. :)