# Add line graph based on new data to series of boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have used the following R script to create two side-side boxplots. One for 1999 and one for 2008:

```
library(tidyverse)
mpg %>% ggplot(aes(as_factor(year), hwy))+geom_boxplot()
```

I have a new data set for manufacturer XYZ that has two observations,one for 1999 and one for 2008:

```
manufacturer <- c("xyz", "xyz")
year <- c(1999, 2008)
hwy <- c(19, 30)
df <- data.frame(manufacturer, year, hwy)
```

Is there a simple way to adding the two observations from the new data set (df) in my boxplot graph?
I have seen a few other similar posts (e.g., [ggplot: adding new data to the existing grouped boxplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153701/ggplot-adding-new-data-to-the-existing-grouped-boxplot)) but the problems/solutions seem to be more complicated and I could not follow them.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for? Basically you can assign a new data frame each time when you call a `geom`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mpg, aes(as.factor(year), hwy)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_point(data = df) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(group = manufacturer))
```

[image]